# Access Nessus administrative portal from another computer

Tags: debian, nessus

I just installed Nessus on a SIEM server running Debian and after the installation I was shown the adress for the admin portal and it was https://servername:8836/

The problem is that I cannot reach this adress from another computer and the SIEM server is without desktop experience so I cannot visit the adress locally either. I have a DNS A record in-place for the IP-adress to match the active directory name (cybersec.ad.company.com) and I cannot either access the Nessus portal by typing https://cybersec.ad.company.com:8836/

When running `sudo /etc/init.d/nessusd status` it says that Nessus is indeed running. What can I do to access the admin portal?

Comment: Please be more specific about "cannot reach this address". What is the actual error message you encounter?

Comment: More specifically I get the regular time-out error when there is no response from the corresponding IP-adress.

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue.